# Hide table header on last page? SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

Is is possible to hide the table header on the last page of the SSRS report?

I have tried using the global variables but I get an exception that those can only be used in the header of the report.

```
=iif(Globals!PageNumber=Globals!TotalPages,true,false)
```

Does anyone know of a work around?

Comment: An easier way might be to right-click the header>Header Properties> Un-check the box that says "Print on last page."

Comment: @bjones that works for the page header but I'm talking about a table header for this one.

Comment: Ah, I misread. Not sure if there is a straight forward way to hide a row for the last page. Perhaps you create an outer group and hide based on the row number for that group.

Answer (score 0):

I think the way to do this is through custom code.

You create a code behind function which is able to access the global variable that you were after:

```
Function GetPageNumber() As String    
    Return Me.Report.Globals!PageNumber    
End Function

Function GetTotalPageNumber() As String    
    Return Me.Report.Globals!TotalPages    
End Function
```

and then use this in your hidden expression for the table header:

```
=IIF(code.GetPageNumber = code.GetTotalPages, true, false)
```

Comment: I didn't verify this through a report right now, so let me know if you hit a snag

Comment: Thanks Daniel this looks plausible. Unfortunately I’m not in office until Monday. I will let you know if this works out.